# python - inputting numbers that start with 0

Tags: python, numbers, zero

I'm making a program in python. It is suppose to take in a GTIN number and put in a list and then check if it's valid. The program works, but as soon as I enter a GTIN number that starts with a 0, I get a **"invalid token (, line 1)"** error. I really need a solution because some products have their GTIN numbers starting with a 0.

when I input a number for example:

```
96080832
```

The program works great.

When i put in a number like:

```
00256986
```

I get an error:

```
invalid token (<string>, line 1)
```

pointing to this line:

```
inputtedInt = int(input("Enter the gtin number: "))
```

Whole def:

```
def chooseOption(inputInt): 
while(inputInt > 0 and inputInt < 4):
    if(inputInt == 1):
        print("you picked option number 1")
        showOptions()
        break
    elif(inputInt == 2):
        print(" ")

        inputtedInt = int(input("Enter the gtin number: "))
        gtin = map(int,str(inputtedInt))
        checkValidity(gtin, 2)



        print(" ")
        showOptions()
        break
    elif(inputInt == 3):
        print("you picked option number 3")
        showOptions()
        break
else:
    option = int(input("Error - enter a number from 1 to 3. : "))
    chooseOption(option)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you showed us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please include example input, expected output, actual output, and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: What's the line after the error points to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using Python 2. In Python 2, `input` tries to evaluate the input string as a Python expression, and a leading `0` on a numeric literal in Python 2 syntax means that the number is in [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), or base 8. Since `8` and `9` are not valid digits in base 8, this input constitutes a syntax error.

If you were supposed to be using Python 3, get on Python 3. If you're supposed to be on Python 2, use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of `input`.

Additionally, if you care about preserving things like leading zeros, you should keep the input as a string and only call `int` on it when you want to do math on it as an integer.

Comment: This is almost certainly the issue, but should probably add a note about not round-tripping input through `int` if he wants to preserve leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Error is raised because you are mapping str ant/to int in line:

```
gtin = map(int,str(inputtedInt))
```

for example if you ty to run:

```
a = 005
```

You will get following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
a = 005
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Sollution -> you should use stringsfor GTIN number :)